# Excel: Formula to help calculate profits

Tags: excel, excel-formula, spreadsheet

I am stuck and have been watching videos and googling a lot today.

My problem is that i need to calculate the tax to deduct as well as deduct the wholesale cost of the product on an excel spread sheet.

There are 3 regions **east, west and central** all with different tax amounts.

- East is an $0.15 tax with a $50$ price deduction
- Central is an $0.18 tax with a $40 price deduction
- West is an $0.18 tax  with a $30 price deduction

**Revenue before tax - E2**

**Region - B2**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOyzU.jpg)

I have tried =IF(B2="east",G2*0.15, '')IF(b2="central",G2*0.18,'')

I am unsure what to put in the if false slot or if I'm even on the right track.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Is the deduction before or after tax?

Comment: Also. you need to standardize your data. You have different capitalization as well as misspellings.  East, EAST, Eastt, etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When facing a problem like yours it's good to remember the basic rule of Excel, "Never put data into a formula". Data belong in a worksheet. Formulas merely manipulate them. Accordingly, you need a table like this one.

[image]

Now the solution is easy - or it would be if your description was unambiguous. I presumed that what you call "price reduction" is in fact a tax free portion of the sale. So, if the value of the sale is $200 tax will be paid on an amount smaller than this. Of course, this leads to the possibility of a negative tax which is unlikely to be on offer. Therefore the formula to be employed is [Tax base] = [Sale Amount] - [Tax excempted amount], but not less than zero.

Based on the above presumption the formula below will do the job if you named the table pictured above as "Taxes". If you didn't name it, the default name might be `Table1` and you can change that name in the formula.

```
=G2+MAX(ROUND((G2-VLOOKUP(B2,Taxes,3,FALSE))*VLOOKUP(B2,Taxes,2,FALSE),2),0)
```

I point out that the formula also rounds the result. This is important in a sheet like yours because you can't afford the total in column H to be different from what you see, and all you see is 2 digits.

Whenever the taxes change you simply change the table and leave the formulas in place. That part is easy. But there is one thing to remember. All the formulas of the past also refer to the table and all your old sales amounts will get "updated". So, when rates change, first Copy/PasteSpecial>Values all existing, or create a new table called `Taxes2020` and start using a new formula referring to that table from the cut-off date forward.

Comment: or add an effective date column to your table, and record the date of the transaction.  So many options!

Answer (score 0):

1. If the price deduction if from the total for the region you should calculate it in two stages, the sum for the region, and then the net after tax.
2. If the deduction is per transaction I would suggest adding a lookup table and add another column to your list which will allow you to calculate all regions with the same formula.

Answer (score 0):

=IF(B2="East",(G2*1.15)-50, IF(b2="Central",(G2*1.18)-40,(G2*1.18)-30))

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't this formula charge a negative tax?

Comment: @Variatus um no.  Why would you think that?

Comment: What would be the charge if G2 were $10?

Comment: @Variatus The total might be less than 0, but the tax wouldn't be.  OP made no condition on capping the deduction

Comment: Look at the screen shot of the OP's worksheet. He needs a column for Sales amount including tax. Your formula doesn't provide that.

Comment: My formula factors in the sales tax as well as the deduction